# Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load in about 1 million lines from a CSV using Load CSV. I am using Neo4j Enterprise 3.2.2 on a Windows machine. I have increased my head stack to 7g but am still hitting the

```
Neo.TransientError.General.OutOfMemoryError
```

Any suggestions for how I can load this CSV using my current cypher query?

The query:

```
     using periodic commit 200 load csv with headers from "file:///LabsTab.Txt" as csvLine fieldterminator '\t' with csvLine where csvLine.ObservationName <> "Cancellation Reason"
    optional match (visit:Visit {VisitID: csvLine.VisitID}) 
    merge (provider:Provider {ProviderName: csvLine.ProviderName}) on create set provider.ProviderID = csvLine.OrderingProviderID
    merge (vlo:VisitLabOrder) on create set vlo.ProviderID = csvLine.OrderingProviderID on create set vlo.FillerOrderNo = csvLine.FillerOrderNo on create set vlo.OrderStartDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.OrderStartDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm") 
on create set vlo.OrderStart = csvLine.OrderStartDtTm
    merge(lab:Lab{FillerOrderNo: csvLine.FillerOrderNo, OrderingProviderID: csvLine.OrderingProviderID, OrderingProvider: csvLine.ProviderName}) 
on create set lab.SpecimenCollectionDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.SpecimenCollectionDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm") 
on create set lab.SpecimentReceivedDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.SpecimenReceivedDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm")
 on create set lab.AnalysisDtTm= apoc.date.parse(csvLine.AnalysisDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm") 
    merge(vlr:VisitLabResult{FillerOrderNo: csvLine.FillerOrderNo, ProviderID: csvLine.ProviderID}) on create set  vlr.ResultStatusChangeDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.ResultStatusChangeDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm") 
on create set vlr.ResultStatusChange = csvLine.ResultStatusChangeDtTm
    merge (labobs:LabObservation{UniversalServiceName: csvLine.UniversalServiceName, UniversalServiceID: csvLine.UniversalServiceID, ObservationName: csvLine.ObservationName, ObservationValue: csvLine.ObservationValue, Units: csvLine.Units}) 
    //Merge (visit)-[r:Lab_tested]->(vlo)-[:Lab_tested]->(lab)-[:Observation_result]->(labobs)
    //merge (lab)-[:Lab_resulted]->(vlr)-[:Lab_resulted]->(visit)
    //merge (vlr)<-[:Ordered]-(provider)-[:Ordered]->(vlo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `LOAD CSV` with `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`.

From [the docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data):

> If the CSV file contains a significant number of rows (approaching
>   hundreds of thousands or millions), `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` can be used
>   to instruct Neo4j to perform a commit after a number of rows. This
>   reduces the memory overhead of the transaction state. By default, the
>   commit will happen every 1000 rows.

You can change the default behavior specifying the desired number after `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`, like:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/csv/artists.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInt(line[2])})
```

Also, `ON CREATE SET` can be specified one time by `MERGE`. Each assignment can be separated by `,`. I don't know if these changes will make difference, but try :)

```
using periodic commit 200 load csv with headers from "file:///LabsTab.Txt" as csvLine fieldterminator '\t'
with csvLine where csvLine.ObservationName <> "Cancellation Reason"
optional match (visit:Visit {VisitID: csvLine.VisitID}) 

merge (provider:Provider {ProviderName: csvLine.ProviderName})
    on create set provider.ProviderID = csvLine.OrderingProviderID

merge (vlo:VisitLabOrder)
    on create set vlo.ProviderID = csvLine.OrderingProviderID,
    vlo.FillerOrderNo = csvLine.FillerOrderNo,
    vlo.OrderStartDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.OrderStartDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"),
    vlo.OrderStart = csvLine.OrderStartDtTm

merge(lab:Lab{FillerOrderNo: csvLine.FillerOrderNo, OrderingProviderID: csvLine.OrderingProviderID, OrderingProvider: csvLine.ProviderName}) 
    on create set lab.SpecimenCollectionDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.SpecimenCollectionDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"),
    lab.SpecimentReceivedDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.SpecimenReceivedDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"),
    lab.AnalysisDtTm= apoc.date.parse(csvLine.AnalysisDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm") 

merge(vlr:VisitLabResult{FillerOrderNo: csvLine.FillerOrderNo, ProviderID: csvLine.ProviderID})
    on create set vlr.ResultStatusChangeDtTm = apoc.date.parse(csvLine.ResultStatusChangeDtTm, "s", "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm"),
    vlr.ResultStatusChange = csvLine.ResultStatusChangeDtTm

merge (labobs:LabObservation{UniversalServiceName: csvLine.UniversalServiceName, UniversalServiceID: csvLine.UniversalServiceID, ObservationName: csvLine.ObservationName, ObservationValue: csvLine.ObservationValue, Units: csvLine.Units}) 
//Merge (visit)-[r:Lab_tested]->(vlo)-[:Lab_tested]->(lab)-[:Observation_result]->(labobs)
//merge (lab)-[:Lab_resulted]->(vlr)-[:Lab_resulted]->(visit)
//merge (vlr)<-[:Ordered]-(provider)-[:Ordered]->(vlo)
```

Comment: I am using periodic commit 2000... I'll try to lower it

Comment: I also have and Eager step.
I tried merging a few rows then merging relationships. I've removed the relationships and am only loading nodes but I still have the Eager step.

After a while I also get "Connection to server lost. Reconnecting..." in the browser but in the command line it says the server is running

Comment: @mzee, I believe that you should edit your question and share the import script with us. Are you still getting the OutOfMemoryError error?

Comment: Added query above. Thank you.

Comment: @mzee what abou the `OutOfBoundsError`? Please try the query with the edits I suggested.

Comment: Still hitting the OutOfMemoryError

Comment: @mzee, the line `merge (vlo:VisitLabOrder)` is right? You are not specifying any property to merge... So I believe that a blank node is being created for each line in the CSV file.

Comment: Got it to work by running one line at a time and found that I had created my indices on Labs not Lab